# Upto which prime is the calculation of $gnu(2^4\cdot3^4\cdot...\cdot p^4)$ feasible?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

The determination of $gnu(n)$, the number of groups of order $n$ upto isomorphism, is very hard in general.

But if no large powers are involved, it should be possible for relatively large numbers.

> Upto which $p$ can $gnu(2^4\cdot 3^4\cdot...\cdot p^4)$ be calculated in a reasonable time?

The first two values are :

```
gap> NrSmallGroups(2^4);
14
gap> NrSmallGroups(2^4*3^4);
3609
```

I currently run GAP for $gnu(2^4\cdot 3^4\cdot 5^4)$

A lower bound for this gnu is :

```
gap> NrSmallGroups(2^4*3^4)*NrSmallGroups(5^4);
54135
```

Comment: If anyone will find new values of $gnu(n)$, please consider submitting them to https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu as issues or pull requests. An example of an issue is [here](https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues/12).

Comment: For holes, please see https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/blob/master/WISHLIST.md

Comment: yes, 2048 is the 1st hole accordingly to http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/software/small/number.html. I am not rushing with updating my database from that table, as I want at the same time leave some trail of records on its verification, runtimes, etc.

Comment: yes, I will edit the files or merge pull request only after I will re-run it. Submitting information about the runtime will help to know what to expect.

Comment: Maybe, you can submit $gnu(180180)=3138$ for me, unless the value is already known.

Comment: Besides filling in the holes in the range [2000..50000], it is interesting to introduce some gamification: what's the largest currently known Gnu(n) calculated with `ConstructAllGroups(n)` (of course excluding values of $n$ for which the formula exists).

Comment: How much does $gnu(180180)$ roughly take?

Comment: What about this : gap> Print(n,":",Collected(Factors(n)),"\n");
1026747117:[ [ 3, 3 ], [ 11, 1 ], [ 23, 1 ], [ 29, 1 ], [ 71, 1 ], [ 73, 1 ] ]
gap> Collected(List(x,Size));
[ [ 1026747117, 30 ] ]
gap> Size(x);
30
gap> ForAll(x,IsGroup);
true
gap> The calculation only takes seconds.

Comment: perfect groups unavailable - very strange. Could you send me a reproducible example?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov If you open a chatroom, I will post you the beginning and the end of a session. The number was $12,514,072$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38927/discussion-between-alexander-konovalov-and-peter).

Comment: Hi Peter. Now `GnuWishlist([1..3000]);` returns `[ 2048, 2240, 2496, 2560, 2592, 2688, 2880, 2916 ]`

Comment: It took me $57$ minutes to find $10,759$ single groups and a pair of groups, probably non-isomorphic. I think, I submitted this incomplete gnu already.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I also repeated the calculation for $2496$ and found $13088$ single groups and $3$ pairs of probably non-isomorphic groups in $2-3$ hours.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know this, but it would be really great if you could communicate with me by means of github issues. If I will comment on them on GitHub, you will get notifications, setting up your notification preferences. It would be perfectly fine to submit a partial result there too: if one knows that one could get there in a couple of hours, this gives enough incentive to pursue this further. We can't rely on comments sitting in MSE questions not even relevant to them. They are too easy to overlook (and in theory could be even deleted by moderators, though I'm not thinking there is a risk)

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22non-isomorphism+check+needed%22

Comment: If you mean https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues/23 then yes obviously - I have notifications set up properly, so I will notice everything. I have even posted there a question addressed to you. See https://help.github.com/articles/about-notifications/ to set up your notifications, if they are not appearing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39974/discussion-between-peter-and-alexander-konovalov).

Comment: Glad that upgrade works. Not surprising that intermediate calculations during the construction require more memory than just retrieving from the database. For timeout, see http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap5.html#X782F88AC7B6DC4F9 and  there are examples in https://github.com/gap-system/gap/blob/master/tst/testinstall/timeout.tst

Comment: May be a good idea. However, the best way to let me know about such suggestions is to submit an issue on GitHub. I understand that MathSE is convenient, but not for managing software development projects. If you will leave it as a comment here, I may forget about it. If you will create an issue, it will stay open until it will be addressed, and it will be advertised so maybe someone else will answer in a comment or even submit a pull request, if I will not have time for that myself.

Comment: BTW, what happened to your attempt to run gnu(810000) ?

Comment: try `CallWithTimeout(rec(seconds:=1),ConstructAllGroups,100);` and `CallWithTimeout(rec(seconds:=1),ConstructAllGroups,1000);`

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: You may find GAP function GnuByConstructAllGroups to generate submission text useful: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/master/lib/grpconst.g

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I tried to submit my project "Find a prime factor" on github but I think, it is not very well yet. Please help me to establish a sensible layout.

Comment: Found it - good for a start, let's chat some time how to give it more structure

Comment: It is public project, so it is visible, but you need to promote your project somehow to make it discoverable by potential contributors. For example, you may post a comment on a relevant question(s) on MathSE

Comment: See e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134984/getting-attention-for-my-open-sourced-project

Comment: I'd expect PARI/GP to be faster than GAP. Have you tried to ask this at the PARI/GP Forums? Also, it surely matters, since with version control you're collaborating with past and future self, even if there are no other contributors yet.